# Mac OS X Java doesn't draw initially

Tags: java, swing

Trying to work with basic swing on Java keeps giving me issues.
When the JFrame is created by the runtime, none of the components are drawn initially, you have to resize the window to invoke paint() apparently? Is there a simple fix to this that I'm missing?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LabTen extends JFrame{

    int x, y;

    public LabTen(){
        this.setSize(200,200);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().add(new Board()); //do this in the constructor    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LabTen one = new LabTen();
        one.repaint();
    }       
}
//mouseListener has more things when we're going in and out so you should have it too
//write on the component or pannel, not the frame
class Board extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    int mouseX, mouseY;

    public Board(){
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){           
        this.mouseX = e.getX();
        this.mouseY = e.getY();
        this.repaint(); 
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        //do nothing...
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){         
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){         
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){         
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //g.drawString("(" + this.mouseX + ", " + this.mouseY +  ")", this.mouseX,this.mouseY);
        //this uses the default way
        // g.drawLine(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2, this.mouseX, this.mouseY);

        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.mouseX - this.getWidth()/2, 2) + Math.pow(this.mouseY - this.getHeight()/2, 2));          
        int centerX = this.getWidth()/2;
        int centerY = this.getHeight()/2;

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            double distanceX = 
            g.drawLine(centerX, centerY, (centerX))
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: as a side note, it works under windows and under X11 forwarding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it completely the wrong order. Do it this way:

1. Add the component

   ```
   this.add(new Board());
   ```
2. Set the preferred size

   ```
   this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
   ```
3. Pack the frame

   ```
   this.pack();
   ```
4. Set the frame visible.

   ```
   this.setVisible(true);
   ```

Of course, `this` is your JFrame.

Comment: that was a lot easier than i thought it would be. my professor does his code examples in class in windows and apparently oracles version of java doesn't care when you add the component. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Once you're done setting up your `JFrame`, you should call `jFrame.pack()` and `jFrame.setVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

All components need to be added to the container before it's *realized*.